# How to find the datanode where a particular file is stored and read from while running an MR Job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-computing

I have 9 files each of size equal to BlockLength of the cluster , stored in hadoop .
I need to get the addresses of the datanodes where the files are present . The replication factor is 3 .

Is there any hadoop API to do this or any other possible way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the java code, you can use the following class

```
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSck
```

Using this method

```
doWork(final String[] args)
```

This will create a URI internally and print all the details using System.out.

Answer (score 2):

The command to find the blocks and data node of a file is as given below

```
 hadoop fsck /user/tom/part-00007 -files -blocks -racks
```

This displays the following result

```
/user/tom/part-00007 25582428 bytes, 1 block(s): OK
0. blk_-3724870485760122836_1035 len=25582428 repl=3 [/default-rack/10.251.43.2:50010,
/default-rack/10.251.27.178:50010, /default-rack/10.251.123.163:50010]
```

This specifies the datanodes where replicas are placed.